# Aspnet_Compiler to publish all dlls other than modified

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, msbuild-task, aspnet-compiler

In our continuous integration process we are using Aspnet compiler to publish the source. But while doing, it only publishes the modified dlls.

Our task is like

```
<AspNetCompiler
              VirtualPath = "DeployTemp" 
              PhysicalPath = "Physical path"
              TargetPath = "Target path"
              Force = "true"
              Debug = "false"
              Updateable = "true"/>
```

What we want is to publish the whole dlls not the modified ones. ie we want a rebuild of the 
whole solution.

When we searched we found an option **-c** in **aspnet_compiler** for this. But we don't know how to apply it here. Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Clean** option - its equivalent of `-c` command line option. For example:

```
<AspNetCompiler
              VirtualPath = "DeployTemp" 
              PhysicalPath = "Physical path"
              TargetPath = "Target path"
              Clean="true"
              Force = "true"
              Debug = "false"
              Updateable = "true"/>
```

For more information, see the [documentation for the AspNetCompiler task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164291.aspx).